# Is there a way to create several implementations of JAX-RS-annotated interface?

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly

I have declared the next interface:

```
public interface IArea {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Path("/")
Response get(
        @QueryParam("param1") String param1,
        @QueryParam("param2") String param2
);

}
```

I implement two stateless beans, using this interface:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/first")
public class FirstController implements IArea {

    public Response get(String param1, String param2) {
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }

}


@Stateless
@Path("/second")
public class SecondController implements IArea {

    public Response get(String param1, String param2) {
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }

}
```

As result we have unknown error, during call both endpoints:

> **org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456:**
>   **Argument bean must not be null**
>    at org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNotNull(Preconditions.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:703)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.getReference(ForwardingBeanManager.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.getReference(BeanManagerProxy.java:86)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiConstructorInjector.construct(CdiConstructorInjector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:312)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:441)
>     ... 51 more

If I implement single bean, for example, FirstController, server works fine.

In both cases "resource-methods" in "Deployment" tab are correct.

Our platform is Wildfly 12.0.0.Final. Java EE 8.

Comment: I tried your example in WF10 (not 12) + JEE8. It's working very fine (not surprinsingly as your code seems perfectly correct).

Answer (score -1):

Try to fix the end point, you have the following:

- localhost:8080//first
- localhost:8080//second

You have one "/" from the interface and one "/" from the implementation...

---

And you have no endpoint on:
localhost:8080/
So it wants 2 parameters (always).

Hopefully this helps.